# Pass all event attributes implicitly with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a component (using Flow) and this how how it is looking like so far:

```
const HitSlopHelperComponent = ({
  children: React.Node,
  width: String,
  height: String,
  onMouseEnter?: Function,
  onMouseLeave?: Function}) => ()
```

However, I realise that I want to accept event handlers no matter what they are and it would be great not to have to list them all.

I could pass a map of event names and callbacks as prop, but I was wondering whether there is a React built-in way that allows me to pass any event handler as prop and be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer props to your component:

```
const HitSlopHelperComponent = ({ children: React.Node, ...rest }) =>
  <div {...rest} >{children}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `rest destructuring pattern` and pass on those to the Element. However make sure that all other props that are not event handlers should `destructured` separately or else you would start to see warning about unknown props

```
const HitSlopHelperComponent = ({
  children: React.Node,
  width: String,
  height: String, 
  ...others
}) => (
   <div {...others}>{/* things you want here */}</div>
)
```

About **[rest destructuring pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)**:

> Assigning the rest of an array to a variable
>
> When destructuring an array, you can unpack and assign the remaining
>   part of it to a variable using the rest pattern:
>
> ```
> var [a, ...b] = [1, 2, 3];
> console.log(a); // 1
> console.log(b); // [2, 3]
> ```
>
> **Note** that a SyntaxError will be thrown if a trailing comma is used on the left-hand side with a rest element:
>
> ```
> var [a, ...b,] = [1, 2, 3];
> // SyntaxError: rest element may not have a trailing comma
> ```

Note: React before v16, unknown attributes were not being passed on to the DOM and React would throw a warning for it. However v16 onwards it would pass all the attributed to the DOM

> According to the React v16 upgrade feature docs:
>
> In the past, React used to ignore unknown DOM attributes. If you wrote
>   JSX with an attribute that React doesn’t recognize, React would just
>   skip it. For example, this: // Your code:
>
> ```
> <div mycustomattribute="something" />
> ```
>
> would render an empty div to the DOM with React 15:
>
> ```
> // React 15 output:
> <div />
> ```
>
> In React 16, we are making a change. Now, any unknown attributes will
>   end up in the DOM:
>
> ```
> // React 16 output:
> <div mycustomattribute="something" />
> ```

Comment: I would like to make sure I am just accepting additional event handlers - that is why I wonder whether there is a React specific way.

Comment: There isn't any React specific way of doing it, you need to take care of it yourself

Comment: Before v16, only the attributes understood by the DOM element would be passed though to it and rest ignored with a warning, however with the latest version all attributes are passed through and its upto the user to take care of it